# Add identifying string into user agent string to hide div only in Android app

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, user-agent, getelementbyid

I have a div called `downloadapp` that I'd like to display to users who visit my website with the browser of their smartphone instead of using my Android app. So I need to hide that div for users who already use my app.

First I used `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished` but visitors kept seeing the div for a few seconds before it disappears. Then someone gave me the advice to add an identifying string (e.g: "my app") into the app's user agent string with the below result. Unfortunately the div still won't disappear from the beginning in my app so what am I missing here?

**Webpage's html + js code:**

```
<head>
<script>
    if (navigator.userAgent.endsWith("myapp")) {
        document.getElementById("downloadapp").style.display = "none";
    } else { 
        document.getElementById("downloadapp").style.display = "inherit";
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="downloadapp">    
    <a href="market://details?id=example"><img src="/example.png"></a>
</div>
</body>
```

**Code Android Webview:**

```
private void startWebView(String url) {
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(webView.getSettings().getUserAgentStri‌​ng() + "; myapp");
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      

    //On error, open local file
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/myerrorpage.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
        view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('downloadapp').style.display = 'none'; void(0);");
} 

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('downloadapp').style.display = 'none'; void(0);");
    }   

});

webView.loadUrl(url);

}
```

Comment: What if you make the div hide by default, and then if the userAgent doesn't is from your app show it?

Answer (score 0):

You made mistake when set user agent. Replace this:

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(webView.getSettings().getUserAgentStri‌​ng() + "; myapp");
```

With This

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("myapp");
```